# I just want a resampled dataframe

Tags: pandas

How do I get the exact values back from a `dataframe`, just sampled at `monthly` intervals? If I say this, `df` is no longer a `dataframe`?

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.resample('1M')
```

So if `df` is say OHLC on daily data, I want `df` to be OHLC on monthly data.

It seems like there used to be a `how`, but now I get an error:

```
df= df.resample('1M', how=ohlc_dict)
```

It's incredible, all the resample and groupby examples apply a function after resampling or grouping. Talk about side effects. I just want the same `dataframe` at a different sampling rate!

Comment: Right now you are basically just grouping the data in 1-month intervals. Each group contains several records (one for each day in the month).  How do you want to aggregate the data/ perform the downsampling? Do you want the average of all records? Do you want only the first record of each month? There are countless options.

Comment: Very clumky:  data = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', axis=0,
                      freq='M')).agg({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close':'last','Volume':'sum'})

Comment: `data = data.resample('1M').agg({'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Close':'last','Volume':'sum'})` should work

Comment: Thing is, I don't want any aggregation. I just want the value at "sample" lengths apart and all the other values to go away and play no part in the dataframe!

Comment: that means that you only want the first record/ day of each group/ month, right?